# About the Regular Expression difference between Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux

The following 'target' is a part of my build.xml. Basically, it will call the 'less4j-1.7.0.jar' to compile all the files end with ".less" in "jsp/jsp_1/css/less" folder into ".css" files in the folder "jsp/jsp_1/css/less".

```
<target description="Compile less to css" name="compile-less0">
<property name="lessFiles0" value="jsp/jsp_1/css/less/*.less"/>
<property name="desFolder0" value="-o jsp/jsp_1/css"/>
    <exec executable="java" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="-jar lib/less4j-1.7.0.jar"/>
        <arg line="-m"/>
        <arg line="${lessFiles0}"/>
        <arg line="${desFolder0}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

This runs very well in the Windows OS. However, when I try to run the same ant script in my Linux server, I got the following errors:

```
compile-less0:
 [exec] Errors produced by compilation of jsp/jsp_1/css/less/*.less
 [exec] ERROR The file jsp/jsp_1/css/less/*.less does not exists.
 [exec] Could not compile the file jsp/jsp_1/css/less/*.less
```

I am thinking if this have some relation with the regular expression format. The "*.less" means all the files end with ".less". And in Windows, it works very well. But why there is error when running this in Linux?

Comment: From my experience, it should work fine in Linux.

Comment: If some string contains `*` it doesn't mean it is regex (I removed this tag from your question). It could be also wildcard in path representing *any characters* (in regex you would have to write it as `.*`).

Comment: well...but It doesn't work in Linux in fact...

Comment: @Pshemo Then How should I make the change?

Comment: Does your Ant file have a `basedir` set?  If so, does it help if you change the references for your folders from `jsp/jsp_1/...` to `${basedir}/jsp/jsp_1/...`?